# How can start a process and stop the process if "error" string appear in the console output strings in one line commands set

Tags: command-line, cmd, ffmpeg, console, find

Now I want one line cmd commands set which start a process and monitor the consol output strings stream. And so if error message appear in the process's console output, then could stop the process immediately.

For example, I tried below commends sets, but failed. It seems find command didn't get any strings streams in which search key word "error"

> ffmpeg "endcoding process options set"   |   find "error" && exit

or,

> ffmpeg "endcoding process options set"   2>&1   find "error" && exit

Is there any solutions about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What sort of errors are you looking for? Any?

Comment: @Mulvya When using redirection, error massage is "[NULL @ 000000000215a2c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'find'
find: Invalid argument".  And when using pipe, there's no error massage, but also no effect of find command's extraction.

Comment: But now I find a way of combining redirection & pipe in the web, like this  " 2>&1 | ", so it's applicable for monitoring to that situation as follows..  ( ffmpeg "endcoding process options set" 2>&1 | find "error" && exit  )  but process stopping action is not solved.;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to exit ffmpeg if an error is thrown then add `-xerror` to your ffmpeg command, which will cause ffmpeg to exit upon error.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Mulvya. But it's absent in my ffmpeg options table. As tested with "-xerror" option, no effect. In spite of errors, my ffmpeg continue the process. The version of ffmpeg I'm using is ffmpeg version is a Zerano build of git-2017-12-30-97b8943.